# Prove that, for $p> 1$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_n\|_p = +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I need some help with this one, a hint would be greatly appreciated:

> Let $f_n \geq 0$ and $f_n \in L^1\quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\|f_n\|_1 =1$ for all $n$.
>
> Suppose also that for each $\delta >0$: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\{|t|>\delta\}} f_n = 0$$
>
> Prove that, for $p> 1$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \|f_n\|_p = +\infty$$

p.s: I had asked a similar question yesterday, but there were some typos in my textbook and the statement was false. This is the correct statement, according to my professor.

Comment: Could you please tell us what was the textbook? I would like to have a source of similar problems. Thanks

Comment: @user3669039 Sorry, the book is written in Greek!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start from here:
let $\delta > 0$ be fixed. Then
$$
1 = \int f_n = \int_{\{|t|\leq \delta\}} f_n + \int_{\{|t| > \delta\}} f_n
\leq (2\delta)^{1/p'} \left(\int_{\{|t| \leq \delta\}} |f_n|^p\right)^{1/p} +
\int_{\{|t| > \delta\}} f_n
$$
$$
\leq
(2\delta)^{1/p'} \|f_n\|_p +
\int_{\{|t| > \delta\}} f_n.
$$
If $L := \liminf_n \|f_n\|_p$ you get that, for every $\delta > 0$,
$$
1 \leq (2\delta)^{1/p'} L,
$$
which clearly implies $L = +\infty$.

Comment: by p' you mean p/p-1 ? (I suppose you're using Holder's inequality)

Comment: Yes, sure. (For $p>1$ your $p'$ is finite.)

Comment: Yep. Nice one, thanks a lot.